# Root DialogHost giving a blank window

Tags: material-design-in-xaml

I want to set up a root DialogHost, for multiple dialogs.  Problem is that it blanks the window.  I looked at the demo and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  Created a simple app, that only has the Material Design Nuget and the dialog;

```
<Window x:Class="DailogTest2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DailogTest2"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <materialDesign:DialogHost Identifier="RootDialog" >
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Amazing Program!" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="50"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
</Window>
```

This returns a blank window.  I know it something super simple but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copy your code into an example project, it shows the textbox.
Is your App.xaml correct? For materialdesign in xaml 2.6.0 you have to use this syntax, because the one in the wiki is only working for 3.0 which is still only a preview version.

```
<Application blablabla>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Purple.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```